# is App() always called after marketplacedetailtask?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a trial and buy mode for my WP7 app. I read that IsTrial() should not be called repeatedly so I am storing the result of this method in a static variable in App() constructor.

When the user clicks the Buy button in the app bar, MarketPlaceDetailTask is launched where the user can buy or cancel.  If they cancel, then I am noticing that App() gets called which in turn calls IsTrial() to set my static variable.

Is this always the case that App() will be called regardless of whether the user clicks Buy or Cancel or goes back by hitting the back button.

Thanks
Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application constructor (`App()`) will always be called after tombstoning.

If you're concerned about the repeated calls to `IsTrial()`, don't be in this scenario.

Comment: So, this is a good place to set a static variable of IsTrialMode by calling this function IsTrial(), correct?  That way, for the other pages of the application, a call to IsTrial() is no longer needed.  Please advise.

Comment: @Pratik yep, that's a good place to do it. Or you could hide it behind a custom property which defers loading it until it's first need.